# add <br> tags at mobile or under specific resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add br tag for mobile view resolution like 320px - 480px. I have tried margin top , bottom but not working. So please help me.

I want add br tag in between these two anchor tag. following two a tag like this.

```html
<a class="ww" href="counseller.html">Career Counsellor</a> 
<a class="xx" href="mentors.html"> Career Mentor</a>
```

Comment: you can use @media to display `<br />`....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use media query

The class `mobile` is applied to the `<br />`. When the `width` of the browser is less than 320px, the class inside the media query will be applied and the element is shown.

```css
.mobile {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 320px) {
  .mobile {
    display: block;
    /* Add other properties here */
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="ww" href="counseller.html">Career Counsellor</a>
<br class="mobile" />
<a class="xx" href="mentors.html"> Career Mentor</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be not to use `<br />` tag but to apply block view property and apply margins on the a class only on mobiles with media queries! This way you would not need to add additional br tags, it would be much easier to handle later.

Answer (score 1):

If you using bootstrap you can Also do Simple code which does not need any custom media class in css just like that :

```html
<a class="ww"  href="counseller.html">Career Counsellor</a>
<br class="visible-xs"/>
<a  class="xx"  href="mentors.html"> Career Mentor</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it adding class to br like this:

```
.my-class{
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {

    .my-class{
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

and add the br tag between your `<a>` like this:

```
<a class="ww"  href="counseller.html">Career Counsellor</a>
<br class="my-class"/>
<a  class="xx"  href="mentors.html"> Career Mentor</a>
```

Comment: The media query should be moved below the open class, otherwise the `display: none` will always be applied

Comment: You're using `min-width` that means the media query will be applied when the width of the browser is more than 480px, that is not what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

using "media querys" here css codes

```
.m_br {display:none}
@media screen and (min-witdh : 380px){
    .m_br{
        display:block
    }
}
```

and html codes

```
<a class="ww" href="counseller.html">Career Counsellor</a>
<!-- add class m_br -->
<br class="m_br"> 
<a class="xx" href="mentors.html"> Career Mentor</a>
```